# Query working in phpMyAdmin but not php - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query which works in phpMyAdmin but not via `mysqli_query`:

```
$update_sql = "
UPDATE db SET db.period = ('January-2017') WHERE db.column between '2016-12-16' and '2017/01/29';
UPDATE db SET db.period = ('February-2017') WHERE db.column between '2017-01-30' and '2017/02/26';
";

echo '<p>'.$update_sql.'</p>';

$result_mysqli_query=mysqli_query($link,$update_sql);
if(! $result_mysqli_query) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

The output from `mysqli_error()` gives:

```
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE db SET db.period' at line 2
```

Ive tried surrounding the field names with '`', copying the output from the echo statement to PHP to see if the generated string works the same, but still no joy.

Comment: You need to use mysqli_multi_query for multiple querys, though it would be better if you split them.

Comment: may be do query one by one solve your problem... execute one then other

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It was mysqli_multi_query() that was the solution - thank you !

Comment: *"Query working ..."* - one query - yes, two queries - no. Even in phpMyAdmin, they are two queries (and phpMyAdmin shows you the execution result after each of them). [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) performs **a** query on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### mysqli_multi_query() not mysqli_query()

For anyone else that comes accross this, as per @Lawrence Cherone's comment, it was actually something simple - using mysqli_multi_query() instead of mysqli_query()

```
$update_sql = "
UPDATE db SET db.period = ('January-2017') WHERE db.column between '2016-12-16' and '2017/01/29';
UPDATE db SET db.period = ('February-2017') WHERE db.column between '2017-01-30' and '2017/02/26';
";

echo '<p>'.$update_sql.'</p>';

$result_mysqli_query=mysqli_multi_query($link,$update_sql);
if(! $result_mysqli_query) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one issues like, what are you trying to update here:

```
db.period = ('January-2017')
```

what is the datatype of `db.period` here and the condition:

```
WHERE db.column between '2016-12-16' and '2017/01/29';
```

here you are using two different `date formats`. Resolve these issues and than run the query again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you're right ! In this case, db.period is in date format, but I'm trying to set the period column to a string (varchar).  Also, for the two different date formats, that was just a mistake on my part copying over to SO.  Fixing those doesnt fix the problem Im afraid !

Answer (score 0):

I think your second UPDATE line contains a redundant semicolon.

Try the simple test - does it work for a single UPDATE line?

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE db SET db.period = ('February-2017') WHERE db.column between '2017-01-30' and '2017/02/26'";

echo '<p>'.$update_sql.'</p>';

$result_mysqli_query=mysqli_query($link,$update_sql);
if(! $result_mysqli_query) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```